# Urlscan 3.1 block User Agent

Tags: iis, user-agent, urlscan

I need to block requests from certain User Agents to our Sharepoint Environment that have been identified after going through the IIS logs.

I have tried the below by amending the urlscan.ini config file and doing and iisreset, but it doesn't block anything.

Am I entering the correct strings? I'm copying user agent string from the iis logs

http://blogs.msdn.com/rakkimk/archive/2009/06/12/urlscan-rejecting-the-request-depending-on-the-user-agent-string.aspx

Comment: I can answer this myself now :)
The problem was the strings, taking them directly from the iis logs, they have many + signs, I removed them and hey presto.  
The below deny's opera, firefox and ms access

[options]

RuleList=DenyUserAgent
[DenyUserAgent]
DenyDataSection=AgentStrings
ScanHeaders=User-Agent

[AgentStrings]

;Browsers

Opera/9.64 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.1.1 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5

;Applications

Microsoft Office/12.0 (Windows NT 5.1; Microsoft Office Access 12.0.6320; Pro)

Comment: I think that this will not work in UrlScan because of the ";" sign. The semi-colon is for commenting and so the string will not be matched in full. How did you solve this? How do you escape a semicolon in Urlscan.ini?

Comment: If you have the answer let me know in this question that I have just added: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850833/specifing-string-with-semicolons-in-urlscan-ini

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISAPI_Rewrite for this task,
for example:

## Block spambots

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} (?:Alexibot|Art-Online|asterias|BackDoorbot|Black.Hole|\
BlackWidow|BlowFish|botALot|BuiltbotTough|Bullseye|BunnySlippers|Cegbfeieh|Cheesebot|\
CherryPicker|ChinaClaw|CopyRightCheck|cosmos|Crescent|Custo|DISCo|DittoSpyder|DownloadsDemon|\
eCatch|EirGrabber|EmailCollector|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|EroCrawler|ExpresssWebPictures|ExtractorPro|\
EyeNetIE|FlashGet|Foobot|FrontPage|GetRight|GetWeb!|Go-Ahead-Got-It|Go!Zilla|GrabNet|Grafula|\
Harvest|hloader|HMView|httplib|HTTrack|humanlinks|ImagesStripper|ImagesSucker|IndysLibrary|\
InfonaviRobot|InterGET|Internet\sNinja|Jennybot|JetCar|JOC\sWeb\sSpider|Kenjin.Spider|Keyword.Density|\
larbin|LeechFTP|Lexibot|libWeb/clsHTTP|LinkextractorPro|LinkScan/8.1a.Unix|LinkWalker|lwp-trivial|\
Mass\sDownloader|Mata.Hari|Microsoft.URL|MIDown\stool|MIIxpc|Mister.PiX|Mister\sPiX|moget|\
Mozilla/3.Mozilla/2.01|Mozilla.*NEWT|Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|NetMechanic|NetSpider|Net\sVampire|\
NetZIP|NICErsPRO|NPbot|Octopus|Offline.Explorer|Offline\sExplorer|Offline\sNavigator|Openfind|\
Pagerabber|Papa\sFoto|pavuk|pcBrowser|Program\sShareware\s1|ProPowerbot/2.14|ProWebWalker|ProWebWalker|\
psbot/0.1|QueryN.Metasearch|ReGet|RepoMonkey|RMA|SiteSnagger|SlySearch|SmartDownload|Spankbot|spanner|\
Superbot|SuperHTTP|Surfbot|suzuran|Szukacz/1.4|tAkeOut|Teleport|Teleport\sPro|Telesoft|The.Intraformant|\
TheNomad|TightTwatbot|Titan|toCrawl/UrlDispatcher|toCrawl/UrlDispatcher|True_Robot|turingos|\
Turnitinbot/1.5|URLy.Warning|VCI|VoidEYE|WebAuto|WebBandit|WebCopier|WebEMailExtrac.*|WebEnhancer|\
WebFetch|WebGo\sIS|Web.Image.Collector|Web\sImage\sCollector|WebLeacher|WebmasterWorldForumbot|\
WebReaper|WebSauger|Website\seXtractor|Website.Quester|Website\sQuester|Webster.Pro|WebStripper|\
Web\sSucker|WebWhacker|WebZip|Wget|Widow|[Ww]eb[Bb]andit|WWW-Collector-E|WWWOFFLE|\
Xaldon\sWebSpider|Xenu's|Zeus) [NC]

RewriteRule .? - [F]