# Specifying string with semicolons in UrlScan.ini

Tags: iis, user-agent, ini, urlscan

I want to block user-agents with UrlScan on IIS 6. However I am not able to specify a user-agent with a semicolon in the string. I think this is a very common scenario, but I can't find any answer on how to escape a semicolon in UrlScan.ini (where semicolon are used for commenting). 
This is the rule:

```
RuleList=DenyUserAgent
[DenyUserAgent]
DenyDataSection=AgentStrings
ScanHeaders=User-Agent
[AgentStrings]
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
```

I tested it and it blocks all the user-agents that start with "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1" because it considers the rest of the string as a comment.

Comment: I looked at this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Escape_characters and I tried replacing the semicolon with: \;, \x003B, ;; and also I tried surrounding the whole string with " and with '. Nothing works. I don't know of any other way to escape a semicolon. please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you would need to URL escape it, i.e. %3B

See http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/476/common-urlscan-scenarios/ for examples; one such example they have is blocking semicolon in the querystring to block a SQL injection attack

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly. if I could give you more votes I would.